# Triangle shadow with CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to implement this triangle shadow design with CSS using [image: button]?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But please show your current attempts at this. Google for "CSS only triangle" and you will find lots of tutorials about that. Once you created the triangle, you just have to position it. If you have a concrete problem, you can post that here.

Comment: did you try to use `::before` or `::after` for triangle shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple background and gradient:

```css
.box {
  padding:10px 20px 10px 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) right/calc(100% - 30px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,grey 50%) left/30px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this multiple background is what I need to know, I'll check the doc

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to the [CSS Triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

If you want more information Here are really nice explanations from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

```
#triangle-bottomright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do your work and will work in most of the browsers.

```css
.triangle {
  padding:10px 20px 10px 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#1e1e72,#1e1e72) right/calc(100% - 30px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,grey 50%) left/30px 100%;
    -moz-linear-gradient(#1e1e72,#1e1e72) right/calc(100% - 30px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,grey 50%) left/30px 100%;
    -webkit-linear-gradient(#1e1e72,#1e1e72) right/calc(100% - 30px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,grey 50%) left/30px 100%;
    -op-linear-gradient(#1e1e72,#1e1e72) right/calc(100% - 30px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,grey 50%) left/30px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"> FAMILLE</div>
```

Comment: this is a simple copy of my answer with a broken code .. check the dev tools

Answer (score -1):

try adding a drop shadow filter to the css for the box

```
 filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
```